# Preciso incluir as classes mapeadas no persistence.xml? Java-Eclipse-Maven-Hibernate-H2database

Tags: java, hibernate, eclipse, maven, h2database

estou tentando configurar um projeto Maven no Eclipse com Hibernate e H2 Database. Por isso, estou tentando entender as configurações do persistence.xml, que tive que criar.

Uma dúvida é: preciso incluir as classes que eu vou mapear nesse persistence.xml? Eu peguei um exemplo na internet que tem:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

 <persistence-unit name="tarefas">

   <!-- provedor/implementacao do JPA -->
   <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

   <!-- entidade mapeada -->
   <class>br.com.caelum.tarefas.modelo.Tarefa</class>

   <properties>
    <!-- dados da conexao -->
     <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" 
             value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" 
            value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/fj21" />
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" 
            value="root" />
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" 
            value="<SENHA DO BANCO AQUI>" />

     <!--  propriedades do hibernate -->
     <property name="hibernate.dialect" 
            value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
    <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />

    <!--  atualiza o banco, gera as tabelas se for preciso -->
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />

   </properties>
 </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Tem um atributo/tag "class" que indica a classe Java a ser mapeada. Tenho que fazer isso com todas as classes do meu projeto?:

2- Outra dúvida é: se a resposta acima for sim, como funciona pra indicar o caminho relativo da classe em relação ao local do meu persistence.xml?

Por exemplo: vejam onde estão no meu projeto os .class e o persistence.xml. Como eu indico a localização dos .class nos atributos  do persistence?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode mapear as entidades de duas formas:

1 com a tag class, como você mencionou:

`<class>caminho.inteiro.do.pacote.NomeDaEntidade</class>`

2 com a anotação `@Entity`:

`@Entity
 public class NomeDaEntidade { ... }`

Respondendo a segunda pergunta, como deve ser informado o FQN - Full Qualified Name para a tag class, o Hibernate sabe exatamente onde a classe está.